# How to write an authentication module for my website?

Tags: authentication, authorization, secure-coding

This will sound naive for sure, and it is. Being a recent college graduate, I have been wondering on how do average websites implement their authentication modules. I have been using a table storing username and hash(password) and their roles (for authorization). All I do is string-matching and done! Then install an SSL cert. This sounds too simple in practice !!

Then I look at the enterprise systems which implement JAAS and stuff like that, which sounds too complex for a small-medium business.

How does an average team consider writing an authentication/authorization module ? This is a language/platform agnostic query. I would be obliged to get any suggestions.

Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *don't*. You use the authentication and authorization modules provided by your framework.

My goto web framework is Python's Flask framework. [Flask-Login](http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is an excellent module that provides an easy to use API that handles the bulk of the authentication work. [Flask-Security](http://flask-security.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is another module that encompasses Flask-Login as well as various other security modules. This isn't unique to Python and Flask. Java for example, has [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/).

Don't roll your own. There are quite a few gotchas that you have to take note of when writing authentication and authorization code. Use battle-tested frameworks and save yourself the headache.